# Adicionar elemento filho antes do outro

Tags: javascript, dom

Vou explicar:

Supondo que eu tenha o seguinte código:

```js
const filho = document.createElement('li')
const text = document.createTextNode('Filho 0')

filho.appendChild(text)
document.getElementById('ul-pai').appendChild(filho)
```

```html
<ul id="ul-pai">
    <li>Filho 1</li>
    <li>Filho 2</li>
</ul>
```

Como podem ver, ele insere o filho 0 depois do filho 2.

Supondo que eu queira inserir o mesmo antes do filho 1, ou seja, na posição 0 do array, isso seria possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar o método `insertAdjacentElement`:

```js
const filho = document.createElement('li')
const text = document.createTextNode('Filho 0')

filho.appendChild(text)

document.getElementById('ul-pai').insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', filho)
```

```html
<ul id="ul-pai">
    <li>Filho 1</li>
    <li>Filho 2</li>
</ul>
```

Os parâmetros para `insertAdjacentElement` podem ser:

- beforebegin: antes do elemento informado.
- afterbegin: dentro do elemento, no início antes do primeiro filho.
- beforeend: dentro do elemento, após o último filho.
- afterend: após o elemento.